При попытке перейти на страницу авторизации происходит вечный редирект - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Spring Security 6.4.0
Переношу свой старый веб сервер на новую версию SPring Boot.
Сделал все как описано на сайте, посмотрел много документаций и видео, и где то что-то пошло не по плану. При попытке зайти на адрес http://localhost:8080/ происходит ожидаемый редирект на http://localhost:8080/login, но при этом появляется ошибка в браузере :
Страница недоступна
Сайт localhost выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.
и на этом мои идеи закончились . Сама страница авторизации открывается только в режиме .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults() но и там с ней проблемы(это уже другой вопрос)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

Подскажите, как быть, неделю мучаюсь
